# How to display Image on Kendo grid, not the actual path?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am trying to load images into Kendo grid from the server(network folder). Firstly i have  uploaded the image to the (network folder) and it works fine.

Now i have to read all the images and displays them in the grid(Kendo). The challenge that am having now its that the grid only loads all the actual path of the images on the grid.

How can i display images from network folder, not the path of the images?

It loads this: **\00.00.00.0000\Folder\Settings\BackgroundImage\20170802_173645.jpg**

**Reading the Images**

```
public ActionResult ReadBackgroundImage([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request) 
    {
        try
        {
            List<SettingsModel> list = new List<SettingsModel>();

            //Getting all the images from DirectoryInfo
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(Filelocation);
            var allowedExtensions = new string[] { ".jpg", ".png" };

            var imageFiless = from file in directory.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                              where allowedExtensions.Contains(file.Extension.ToLower())
                              select file;

            foreach (var file in imageFiless)
            {
                SettingsModel img = new SettingsModel();
                img.ImageUrl = file.DirectoryName;
                img.PictureName = file.FullName;
                list.Add(img);
            }
            return Json(list.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content("", ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**View and Kendo grid**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TTAF.Portal.Parts.Web.Models.SettingsModel>()
                            .Name("Grid")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                            columns.Bound(client => client.PictureName).ClientTemplate("#=PictureName#");

                            columns.Bound(x => x.IsSelected).Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input id='chkId' name'chkbox' type='checkbox' #= IsSelected ? checked='checked':'' # class='checkbox' onClick='ValidateMoreClick()' />").Title("Selected Image");

                            }))
```

Comment: convert image to base64 string and use that in view

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Do you mind if you can show me how to do that?

Comment: just a google search will reveal that

Comment: see : http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/e6d71127-1f12-4555-879b-6a859947eafa.aspx

Comment: Do i have to convert it before saving?

Comment: when fetching it, convert it to byte array and then from byte array you can get base64string, when you have that you can look for how to use it in the view to display

Comment: On the view i just want to read it on kendo. no viewbag. Is that possible ?

Comment: not sure how to do it with kendo grid, look at their documentation if it's possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153132/discussion-between-mr-junior-and-ehsan-sajjad).